# How to identify partition migrations is finished for hazel cast?

Tags: java, hazelcast

> Wait until all partition migrations are completed; during migrations,
>   membership changes (member joins or removals) are not allowed

Above is from hazelcast official website.
how to identify the partition migrations already finished?
while partition migrations, if one member left during partition migrations, what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Migration listener for the status of partition migration. Here is the documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-migration-events

If a member leaves during partition migration then a few things could happen:

- if the leaving member was the source of the migration (partitions moving from this member) but it left before the migration even began, then ongoing migration is terminated immediately and new repartitioning calculations happen
- if the leaving member happens to the destination of migration then migration may be completed if the member leaves after the migration commit, otherwise its rolled back and a new repartitioning will be calculated and scheduled
- in all other cases, the migration is allowed to complete first and then new repartitioning is calculated and scheduled